# How to use flask request properly to retrieve data from JSON?

Tags: python, json, request

I looked many questions similar to my title but I have not found any that had same problem as me yet.

I did `requests.post` to post JSON to API restful server. Below is the snippet

```
import requests

def upload_data():
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:8088/"
    data = {"value":"abc123"}
    response = requests.post(url, data=data)

    print response.status_code, response.reason, response.text

upload_data()
```

And for the server side

```
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
from flask import request

class MyAPI(Resource):
    def get():
        pass

    def post(self):
        value = request.data['value']
        response_object = {
            'value':value
        }

        return response_object, 201
```

I was hoping to get the POST function to work by showing the result of `201 Created` with

```
{
    'value':'abc123'
}
```

But whenever I run the script, it gives me error saying that

```
    value = request.data["value"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

I am sorry if this is a bad question but if anyone could show me what I have been missing in this script, I really appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because request data hasn't been parsed into a python dictionary. Were you perhaps thinking of

```
data = json.loads(request.data)
```

However please note that you are not actually posting a JSON body to your flask server. You are posting multipart formdata. So you may probably be looking for the answer posted by luoluo.

One the other hand if you really wanted to deal with json, The correct way to **send** json looks something like this:

```
requests.post(url, json=data)
```

And then the loads as suggested.

Comment: thank you. I knew I must had missed something in my code. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad to have been of help. All the best with your project

Answer (score 1):

The `request.data` is a `string`, while `request.values` is a `MultiDict`.

You need update your code to :

```
value = request.values.get('value')
```

instead of

```
 value = request.data['value']
```

According to the [doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#incoming-request-data)

> **args**
>   A MultiDict with the parsed contents of the query string. (The part in the URL after the question mark).
>
> **form**
>   A MultiDict with the parsed form data from POST or PUT requests. Please keep in mind that file uploads will not end up here, but instead in the files attribute.
>
> **values**
>   A CombinedMultiDict with the contents of both form and args.
>
> **data**
>   Contains the incoming request data as string in case it came with a mimetype Flask does not handle.

Comment: This is great. Thank you for the explanation